# IIS without Admin privileges

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have a login which doesn't have admin privileges, I need to be able to connect to the default web sites available on the same server, if I login to the server with the admin privileges then I am able to see all the websites that are hosted. But if i login with the user which is not running on the admin privileges then none of the websites are visible. Can anyone please suggest what are the privileges that I need to give to the non admin user in order for him to access the websites.

I'm am not able to find the "IIS Manager Users" menu on my IIS.

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Is there no IIS Administrators group?

Comment: Why is this tagged with the 2008-r2 tag? IIS 6 ships with Windows Server 2003.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed.

Comment: AFAIK, there's also no IIS 6.1. @Navee, please edit your question to resolve these discrepancies.

Comment: Is 6.1 the IIS on XP or Vista or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no supported way to do this in IIS 6. You can delegate the ability to manage sites to non-admins in IIS 7 and later, but this does not exist in IIS 6. Either you must be a local admin to manage it, or you need to upgrade to Windows Server 2008 or 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had not installed "Management Services" under "Management Tools of IIS".